# sweet alert 1 animation css color bug

Tags: html, css

btw this is my first post :)
im trying to edit the code but i get this error:

```
/* -----------------------
#  SWEETALERT CUSTOMIZED
------------------------*/

.swal-modal {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.651);
color: #fff;
}
.swal-title {
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.swal-text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
}
/* button */
.swal-button {
padding: 7px 19px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #198754;
font-size: 12px;
border: 1px solid #198754;
}

.swal-button:focus {
box-shadow: none;
}

.swal-button:not([disabled]):hover{
background: transparent;
color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #198754;
}

/* Icons */
.swal-icon--success_hide-corners {
background: none !important;
}
.swal-icon--success:before,
.swal-icon--success:after {
background: none !important;
}
```

[the problem is the white line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivNr6.png)

I want to get rid of this white line i think this is in the ".swal-icon--success_hide-corners" part but i couldnt fint the solution.

Answer (score 0):

i found my solution, I wrote one "_" instead of two "__"
in the line:

```css
.swal-icon--success_hide-corners {
```